# How do I recover a file which cannot be opened due to using Japanese characters in the file path?

Tags: terminal, finder, ms-office, language

I saved a word document to a path similar to: "something/にほん.docx" then closed down Word as it appeared to save successfully. I looked in Finder and the file wasn't there. I opened Word again, and I can see the file in the "Recent documents" folder but when I try to open it I get "this document is either deleted or not currently accessible". Is there a way to recover it? Obviously I can rename it to something using the roman alphabet.

Possibly relevant info:

- I am on macOS 10.13.1 on a 15 Inch Mid-2015 Retina MacBook Pro.
- My Mac system language is English (UK).
- I have enabled hidden files in finder.

I have tried:

- Using the mv terminal command to rename the file. It says the file cannot be found.
- Setting my primary system language to Japanese. Still no sign of the file.

Does anybody have anything else I could try?

Comment: you already tried looking for all the files created/modified in the last X days (1 or "today" if you created the file today) from the finder?

Comment: @GioValerio I had tried that, although your suggestion inspired me to try searching for the filename and it came up - allowing me to rename it and open it. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Even though the file didn't appear in the folder, I searched for it within Finder and it came up. Simply renamed it and then opened it in Word normally.